# Rake RSpec Tasks are not showing up

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, rake

I have an inherited app, running on Rails 3 in Ruby 1.9, and its working fine, but for some reason, when I installed both rspec and jasmine, neither of their rake tasks are showing up when I run rake -T. The Rakefile for the app is just the standard one, and in fact, when I installed Cucumber, its rake tasks show up just fine.

If I type in rake spec, there is no error, but none of my specs are run. But, if I type rspec spec, they all run, just fine. the jasmine tasks error out, saying there is no such tasks.

Any idea why these wouldn't be showing up, but other tasks would?

Comment: Do they show with `rake -P` ? And did you run `rails g rspec:install` ?

Comment: Nope! And if it helps, when I update my rake to 0.9.1, I get this error hwen I run rake spec: WARNING: Global access to Rake DSL methods is deprecated.  Please Include
    ...  Rake::DSL into classes and modules which use the Rake DSL methods.
WARNING: DSL method Uptime::Application#task called at /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@uptime/gems/railties-3.0.7/lib/rails/application.rb:215:in `initialize_tasks'

Comment: did you ever solve the depreciation error?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Do you have rspec-rails in the development group?

http://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/file/gettingstarted

Comment: I had put it in the 'test' group but not dev, thinking 'well, I use it for test, not dev' - but didn't think about the fact that this would be a problem since I run rake as dev! Thanks, sir, you made my day :)

Comment: awesome! i also put mine in just the test group with the same reason lolol. thanks a lot!